# Problem encountered on OTA update in EXPO React Native App

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native, ota

I'm having a problem with OTA updates from EXPO. Indeed, I have an application in which I have configured the updates via EAS and modified the app.json file in order to take the updates into account. Also I rebuilt the application and installed it. I try since, to make remote updates; unable to get the result of the update the application remains exactly the same.

This is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xxxxxx",
    "slug": "xxxxxx",
    "version": "0.1.8",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/xxxxxx.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 300000,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "MAIN",
          "data": {},
          "category": [
            "LEANBACK_LAUNCHER",
            "LAUNCHER"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "visible": "sticky-immersive"
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "hidden": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/logo-square.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to modify the fallbackToCacheTimeout ... nothing. Also, i've tried to prebuild the app and put the version of the SDK in the app.json and AndroidManifest, nothing too.

Any ideas?

Comment: What eas command are you invoking when you push an update. And do you have configured your expo.dev account accordingly? What is the error message.

Comment: Hi Ferry, thanks for your answer.

 I make an eas update on the production environnement. When I make update, i can check the update with the expo app, it works perfectly with the update. 

I think that my expo env is well configured but maybe i've missed something ? What point i've to check ? 

Thanks a lot